# Toggle LED on when Button is pressed PIC

Tags: pic

I've got an [olimex board](https://www.olimex.com/Products/PIC/Proto/PIC-P28-20MHz/) with a [PIC16LF76](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/268/30325b-79977.pdf)(Schematic - PIC IS a different pic):
[image: Schematic of board]

I'm trying to toggle the LED when the button is pressed down, my C code looks like:

```
#include <xc.h>
#pragma config FOSC = HS        // Oscillator Selection bits (XT oscillator)
#pragma config WDTE = OFF       // Watchdog Timer Enable bit (WDT disabled)
#pragma config PWRTE = OFF       // Power-up Timer Enable bit (PWRT enabled)
#pragma config CP = OFF         // FLASH Program Memory Code Protection bit (Code protection off)
#pragma config BOREN = OFF

int main() {
    TRISA = 0x20;
    ADCON0 = 0b111;
    while(1){
        if((PORTA & 0x20)==0) {
            PORTA |= 0x01;
        } else {
            PORTA &= ~0x01;
        }
    }
}
```

Whats going wrong(Something similar would work for Atmel AVR)? My compiler is XC8 and I am using MPLabX. I can confirm the switch works, and so does the LED as I have tested these parts of the olimex board individually and independently without the PIC chip in the board..

EDIT:

I've tried the answers supplied still to no avail. Also the LED is on despite not setting it on.

Comment: I'm not a PIC guy, more AVR  although I don't see a command telling the PIC that RA5 is an input.  if its similar to an AVR, you'll need to tell its directional register that the button pin is an input.  then you'll be able to read its input regsiter.  Once again, I'm an AVR guy

Comment: @ShannonStrutz Thats the TRISA register, this threw me as well DDRA is much clearer.

Comment: Hmm, then I got nothing,  your if and statement looks fine, best of luck.

Comment: I strongly recommend using PORT for reading only. Use LAT if you want to write. It's caused me problems in the past. In your case, you would replace with LATABits.RA0 = 1 etc.

Comment: @BBON this PIC doesn't have LATx registers.

Comment: According to the data sheet you probably need to set ADCON1. Try setting it to 0b111. See page 84 of the data sheet you linked.

Comment: You're not really toggling, just passing the input along, so you can ignore the debouncing comments (for now).

Comment: @m.Alin this is incorrect, the enhanced mid-range 16F devices **do** have LAT registers.  But the 16LF76 is only "normal" mid-range so does **not**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is probably caused by the analogue module. According to page 84 of the data sheet you linked the ADCON1 register needs to be set correctly to enable digital functions on PORTA.

A value of `0b111` is likely to make your code work (but see other answers about debouncing). Various other combinations of values are available in the table for REGISTER 11-2:

[image: REGISTER 11-2 ADCON1 REGISTER]

This type of configuration is common on the smaller 12F and 16F devices, which lack the ability to individually select analogue or digital per-pin.

As Spehro notes in the comments there are a number of ways to find which registers are associated with a port.  The easiest is TABLE 4-2: SUMMARY OF REGISTERS ASSOCIATED WITH PORTA, which looks like this:

[image: TABLE 4-2 SUMMARY OF REGISTERS ASSOCIATED WITH PORTA]

This table becomes even more useful on large devices that have lots of functions such as extended analog features or capture and compare.  Many of these need to be disabled after reset (e.g. comparators) and some might interfere unintentionally if misconfigured (e.g. MSSP).

Note that this table also shows that the 16LF76 does not have LATx registers, so other comments above can be safely ignored for this device.

Comment: You can also look at the example on page 31, where ADCON1 is set to 0x06 (same effect as 0x07). Another hint is to look at TABLE 4-2: SUMMARY OF REGISTERS ASSOCIATED WITH PORTA, which shows that you should look at ADCON1.

Comment: I've set this and still no success.

Comment: @Dean your edit shows you are still setting ADCON0, is this true?  You need to be setting **ADCON1**.

Answer (score 2):

This answer will be similar to my answer [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/97905/35800).

First, you probably need switch debouncing. That is, you want to set a delay in software or use a capacitor from the input to ground. When the switch is pressed, the contact will make and break very rapidly before finally closing and pulling the input pin to ground. Every time it closes it is going to toggle your LED. Thus, you want to filter (low-pass) the changes by attenuating high frequency. Here is a good [debouncing reference](http://www.eng.utah.edu/~cs5780/debouncing.pdf). See pages 12-14.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzYa60.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Next, you may want to set a flag to only toggle once the button has been released. The loop isn't going to stop once you press the button. As long as the switch is closed the loop will continue executing and toggling the LED. Perhaps your current setup works sometimes but not others? That would be because you are seeing where the loop finally stops.

```
while(1)
{
    //Check to see whether the switch is pressed and flag is set.
    //Then, toggle the port and reset the flag.
    if ((PORTA & 0x20)==0 && flag==1)
    {
        PORTA ^= 0x01; //Notice the XOR (toggle) here. No if-statement needed.
        flag = 0;
    }
    //Now, wait until the switch is released until the pin can be toggled again.
    //This way, if you hold the button down, it will not keep toggling the port
    //repeatedly. It will only toggle it once, then wait for the button to be released.
    else if ((PORTA & 0x20)==1 && flag==0)
    {
        flag = 1;
    }
}
```

Another way would be to use an interrupt-on-change if it is available. Then you could have the interrupt trigger on a falling edge and toggle the LED there.